# How to Search from Parsed JSON Data?

Tags: android, json, search

I have a `Custom list view` in my App which shows the `parsed JSON content`. Now i have to search the data from the `list view`.  I saw some similar Questions like me.

[Android parsed json data and add a search functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367655/android-parsed-json-data-and-add-a-search-functionality)

[Implementing SearchView in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar)

But i don't know how to make use of it. So i saw the [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) and changed some in my Activity and added the `Meta data` in the manifest and created a Searchable xml.

But i don't know how get the data from the Listview or from the parsed JSON data.

I am using Material Design in my App. If there is anything New in Search Interface . Pls Let me know.

Thanks in Advance!

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

        private static final String TAG = "Mine";

        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
        public ListView listView;
        private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
        private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
        public String mvideoid;
        public String mstatus;
        ProgressBarCircularIndetermininate progressBar;

        private String URL_FEED = "http://arulnadhan.hol.es/vid.json";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);


            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feed_list);
            feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
            listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            GsonRequest<FeedResult> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<FeedResult>(URL_FEED, FeedResult.class,
                    new Response.Listener<FeedResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(FeedResult response) {
                            feedItems = response.getFeedItems();
                            listAdapter.setData(feedItems);
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addRequest(gsonRequest, TAG);
        }


private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                String name = feedObj.isNull("name") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("name");
                item.setName(name);

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImageUrl(image);
                mstatus=feedObj.getString("status");
                item.setStatus(mstatus);
                // videoid might be null sometimes
                mvideoid = feedObj.isNull("videoid") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("videoid");
                item.setVideoid(mvideoid);
                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 1){
                FeedFragment Frag = new FeedFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, Frag);
                transaction.commit();
            }else if (position == 2){
                VideoFragment Frag = new VideoFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, Frag);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
```