# Android search feature using action bar

Tags: android, listview, searchview, android-searchmanager

How to implement youtube app like search functionality in action Bar ,**How it search strings dynamically from server.and display in list view**. I have no idea how to add dynamic search feature in it , which response from server.

Comment: is it solved?what happen

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: your question is about to search in action bar not filtring

Answer (score 0):

**Step - 1**

If you have more things for the search results then you have to implement **onTextChange** call to the server and **retrieve** the **list** as text change.

or

If you have **small list** you can retrive whole list **onstarting** of the **activity**.

**Step - 2**

set data in adapter of the **AutoCompleteTextView**.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you looking for,Try to use [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                //Do some magic
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //Do some magic
            }
        });
```

Comment: you need to fetch data in your listview and then filter it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367655/android-parsed-json-data-and-add-a-search-functionality see this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView) library.

Code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search: {
                mSearchView.show(true/false); // animate, ONLY FOR MENU ITEM
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Styling SearchView:

```
       <attr name="search_version" format="enum">
           <enum name="toolbar" value="1000" />
           <enum name="menu_item" value="1001" />
       </attr>
       <attr name="search_version_margins" format="enum">
            <enum name="toolbar_small" value="2000" />
            <enum name="toolbar_big" value="2001" />
            <enum name="menu_item" value="2002" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="search_theme" format="enum">
            <enum name="light" value="3000" />
            <enum name="dark" value="3001" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="search_icon_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="search_background_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="search_text" format="string" />
        <attr name="search_text_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="search_text_size" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="search_hint" format="string" />
        <attr name="search_hint_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="search_divider" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="search_voice" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="search_voice_text" format="string" />
        <attr name="search_animation_duration" format="integer" />
        <attr name="search_shadow" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="search_shadow_color" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="search_elevation" format="dimension" />
```